# Regression with subsets in R: Is there a nice solution with a loop or similar?

Tags: r, loops, regression, subset

I have subsets from a dataset and want to perform a regression on these subsets. I can code everything individually but I am looking for a clean and fast solution, probably with a loop.

I made an example dataset from mtcars with 3 subsets: df1, df2, df3.

It would be great if the solution can also be applied in principle to make other analysis: vif, stepwise regression, ANN ...

```
# Define 3 datasets from mtcars: df1, df2, df3
df1 <- mtcars

library(dplyr)
df2 <- mtcars %>%
  filter(cyl <= median(cyl, na.rm = T))
df3 <- mtcars %>%
  filter(cyl > median(cyl, na.rm = T))

# regression 1
model_df1 <- lm(df1$mpg ~ df1$disp + df1$hp)

# regression 2
model_df2 <- lm(df2$mpg ~ df2$disp + df2$hp)

# regression 3
model_df3 <- lm(df3$mpg ~ df3$disp + df3$hp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Storing those subsets in a (named) list would allow you to conveniently use functions from apply- or map-family:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(broom)

df_list <- list()
df_list$mtcars <- mtcars
df_list$lt_median <- mtcars %>% filter(cyl <= median(cyl, na.rm = T))
df_list$gt_median <- mtcars %>% filter(cyl > median(cyl, na.rm = T))

# fit a model on each dataset in df_list, returns list of models:
model_list <- map(df_list, ~ lm(mpg ~ disp + hp, data = .x))
summary(model_list[[1]])
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = mpg ~ disp + hp, data = .x)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -4.7945 -2.3036 -0.8246  1.8582  6.9363 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept) 30.735904   1.331566  23.083  < 2e-16 ***
#> disp        -0.030346   0.007405  -4.098 0.000306 ***
#> hp          -0.024840   0.013385  -1.856 0.073679 .  
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 3.127 on 29 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.7482, Adjusted R-squared:  0.7309 
#> F-statistic: 43.09 on 2 and 29 DF,  p-value: 2.062e-09

# apply tidy / glance / augment from broom to all models in a list,
# either collect results into same data frame
map(model_list, tidy) %>% imap_dfr(~ mutate(.x, dataset = .y))
#> # A tibble: 9 × 6
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value dataset  
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>    
#> 1 (Intercept)  30.7      1.33       23.1   3.26e-20 mtcars   
#> 2 disp         -0.0303   0.00740    -4.10  3.06e- 4 mtcars   
#> 3 hp           -0.0248   0.0134     -1.86  7.37e- 2 mtcars   
#> 4 (Intercept)  38.1      2.59       14.7   2.50e-10 lt_median
#> 5 disp         -0.0546   0.0160     -3.40  3.93e- 3 lt_median
#> 6 hp           -0.0688   0.0277     -2.48  2.53e- 2 lt_median
#> 7 (Intercept)  24.0      4.05        5.94  9.69e- 5 gt_median
#> 8 disp         -0.0186   0.00946    -1.97  7.46e- 2 gt_median
#> 9 hp           -0.0113   0.0126     -0.900 3.87e- 1 gt_median
map(model_list, glance) %>% imap_dfr(~ mutate(.x, dataset = .y))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 13
#>   r.squ…¹ adj.r…² sigma stati…³ p.value    df logLik   AIC   BIC devia…⁴ df.re…⁵
#>     <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <int>
#> 1   0.748   0.731  3.13   43.1  2.06e-9     2  -80.3 169.  174.    283.       29
#> 2   0.699   0.659  2.91   17.4  1.24e-4     2  -43.1  94.2  97.8   127.       15
#> 3   0.320   0.197  2.29    2.59 1.20e-1     2  -29.8  67.6  70.2    57.9      11
#> # … with 2 more variables: nobs <int>, dataset <chr>, and abbreviated variable
#> #   names ¹​r.squared, ²​adj.r.squared, ³​statistic, ⁴​deviance, ⁵​df.residual

# or keep as a list
map(model_list, augment, newdata = head(mtcars[c("mpg", "disp", "hp")], n = 5))
#> $mtcars
#> # A tibble: 5 × 6
#>   .rownames           mpg  disp    hp .fitted .resid
#>   <chr>             <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 Mazda RX4          21     160   110    23.1  -2.15
#> 2 Mazda RX4 Wag      21     160   110    23.1  -2.15
#> 3 Datsun 710         22.8   108    93    25.1  -2.35
#> 4 Hornet 4 Drive     21.4   258   110    20.2   1.23
#> 5 Hornet Sportabout  18.7   360   175    15.5   3.24
#> 
#> $lt_median
#> # A tibble: 5 × 6
#>   .rownames           mpg  disp    hp .fitted .resid
#>   <chr>             <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 Mazda RX4          21     160   110   21.8  -0.815
#> 2 Mazda RX4 Wag      21     160   110   21.8  -0.815
#> 3 Datsun 710         22.8   108    93   25.8  -3.02 
#> 4 Hornet 4 Drive     21.4   258   110   16.5   4.93 
#> 5 Hornet Sportabout  18.7   360   175    6.43 12.3  
#> 
#> $gt_median
#> # A tibble: 5 × 6
#>   .rownames           mpg  disp    hp .fitted .resid
#>   <chr>             <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 Mazda RX4          21     160   110    19.8   1.18
#> 2 Mazda RX4 Wag      21     160   110    19.8   1.18
#> 3 Datsun 710         22.8   108    93    21.0   1.82
#> 4 Hornet 4 Drive     21.4   258   110    18.0   3.41
#> 5 Hornet Sportabout  18.7   360   175    15.4   3.34
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, it works! Is there a way to make an output with stargazer? I tried it with: out <- map(model_list, tidy) %>% imap_dfr(~ mutate(.x, dataset = .y))
library(stargazer)
stargazer(out, type = "html", out = "out.html") 
-> it does not give output

Comment: @MichaelSchmeisser , try to convert the tibble to data.frame first:  `stargazer(as.data.frame(out), type = "html", out = "out.html")`

Comment: It does not give the full output as is shown in the console. I am looking for an output, where the results are shown for every variable in each subset (like it is shown in the console). It works with library(writexl) write(_xlsx(out, "/Users/....") but it makes it an excel file and that is not formatted so nice like in stargazer. Nevertheless, many thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @MichaelSchmeisser , if it's just summary you get from stargazer, this can be disabled: `stargazer(as.data.frame(out), type = "html", out = "out.html", summary = FALSE)` . There are also number of other table formatters out there, starting with `knitr::kable()` & kableExtra

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. You are a pro! I made a note and will check knitr:kable() later. However, stargazer worked for my stuff.

Comment: Regarding the stargazer output it would be great to have the html output showing whether some variable is significant or not (like 0.23***, 0.1** and so on). This is the typical default when using stargazer but it is not showing up in the results when I use stargazer(as.data.frame(out), type = "html", out = "out.html", summary = FALSE). Can I turn this on? I read in the help for the stargazer function but I could not find it. Thanks for giving me an idea.